# how to show the sum of time for same date with different project names in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want if someone choose the similar date for example 25th Oct 23 for two different project with different comment and Time then it should show the Total as total of those 2 time. for project1 its time is 3 and for project2 its time is 5 then total column in 2nd row should show its sum 2+5 equal to 8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30KOL.png)

this is what I am geeting but in 2nd row I want Total column value should be 8.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.